# Meaning of statement in Java Functional Interface Function

Tags: java, java-8, functional-interface

I recently was learning functional interfaces in Java and so the ***Function*** Interface.
When I came across the definition of `identity static method` in it, the very first thing that confused me was :

```
static <T> Function<T, T> identity() {
        return t -> t;
    }
```

What is meaning of Function<T,T> in the return type? Where does the lowercase t in function definition come from ? Elaborated explanations are always helpful.

Comment: The meaning of the `Function<T,T>` return type, is that you can chain the calls over and over, for example you can do `identity().andThen(--another function here --).compose( -- another function here --) .. .apply(x)` where `x` is the object you want to apply the previous chained calls

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html

Comment: You have to understand lambda expressions, to understand where the lowercase `t` comes from. In short, it comes from right where you see it, to the left of the `->` arrow, as that’s a parameter declaration *defining* the parameter’s name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> static <T> Function<T, T> identity() {
> ```

The first `<T>` declares a **type variable**. It's similar to declaring a normal variable, e.g.:

```
void foo() {
  int x; // this declares a variable
}
```

except:

- It is called `T`.
- a normal variable refers to a value. A type variable refers to a type, hence the name 'type variable'. Just like `int x;` means: "`x` stands in for an int value; where you would write e.g. `5 + 2` you can also write `5 + x` and you substitute whatever value x holds at that time instead of '2' - a type variable substitutes a type. Where you normally write `String z;` you can write `T z;` - meaning: `z` is a variable. The type of this variable is whatever type the `T` typevar means.
- It has no bounds - meaning, T can be any non-primitive type. Object, Number, InputStream, SomeTypeIDeclared, whatever you want.

Unlike actual variables, typevars are a figment of the compiler's imagination. The compiler uses them to make code make sense and be better type checked. The runtime (`java.exe`) does nothing with them.

Hence, they serve to **link things**: You use them to say: "This method takes one parameter and returns a value. The type of the parameter can be whatever you want; this method returns the same type as what you pass in. As an example.

Here, checking `Function`'s javadoc, its first type argument is the type of the *input* of the function, the second is the type of the *output*.

The only reason we need `<T>` here is to link em up: We want to express the notion of a function whose input type is the same as its output type. That's obvious once we consider what the `identity()` method does: It returns a **function** that just returns its input. Hence, the type of its output is naturally identical to the type of its input.

> ```
> return t -> t;
> ```

This defines a function - it's lambda syntax. It's shorthand for:

```
class MyAnonymousType<T> implements Function<T, T> {
  public T apply(T t) {
    return t;
  }
}

return new myAnonymousType<T>();
```

The first `t` is short for the `T t` in `apply(T t)` - there is no need to write `apply` because the compiler knows you are attempting to return a `java.lang.function.Function` and that is a functional interface (an interface with only one method) - it knows you want to implement that method, so no need to specify its name, the compiler can figure it out. You don't need the `T` for the same reason - the compiler figures it out from the signature of that one method in your functional interface.

`->` is short for: ... and now for the implementation of this one method in the Function interface. And the implementation is simply `t` - short for `return t;` (`return` is implied *unless* you add braces). You can also write:

```
return t -> {
  return t;
};
```

and even:

```
return (T t) -> {
  return t;
};
```

if that helps clear things up for you.

The end result is a function (named `identity`) that returns a function (we're getting a bit meta in here!) - the function returned will adapt to whatever specific type you have in mind, as long as you are looking for a function that returns the same type that it takes in, and you want an implementation of such a function that simply returns the input verbatim (which naturally therefore means the returned thing has the same type as the provided thing).

Comment: "Unlike actual variables, typevars are a figment of the compiler's imagination."
That is not true, type variables are accessible at runtime, e.g.: 
`Function.class.getDeclaredMethod("identity").getTypeParameters()`

Comment: @AlexR The runtime (`java.exe`) treats them as comments. It has no idea what they mean nor does it apply any safety. The vast majority of generics isn't available at runtime. The only ones that are, are where they are used in signatures (the type of a field or the type of a method's return type or parameter or throws clause), and the reason they are available, is solely for the purpose of the compiler. It's somebody who is fairly new to java, your pedantic 'buuut acshually...' comment is didactically a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

From [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html):

> This is a functional interface and can therefore be used as the assignment target for a lambda expression or method reference.

The Function contains 4 methods:

- apply()
- andThen()
- compose()
- identity()

`identity()`:

> This method returns a function that returns its only argument.

Syntax:

`static <T> Function<T, T> identity()`

where T denotes the type of the argument and the value to be returned

Returns: This method returns a function that returns its own argument

Answer (score 0):

When in doubt, always consult the docs first - [Function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html).

`<T> Function<T, T>` means function, whose return type is the same as the input type.

`t -> t` is a lambda expression, defining the function, it means you return the input. That is explained in the docs as well:

> Returns a function that always returns its input argument.

Additionally you should go through the lambda expression tutorial from Oracle - [Lambda Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html)

Answer (score 0):

let's take a look at the Function interface definition

`public interface Function<T, R> {}` **<T,R>** means that this interface can take any type of class T and return different type R (does not enforce the output type to be the same as the input)

> What is meaning of Function<T,T> in the return type?

we are returning a Function that accepts and returns the same type of object. **forcing the same Type**

> Where does the lowercase t in function definition come from ?

this is lambda expression, as Function is functional interface that has only one abstract method apply(T t) that takes one input t and we are returning the same input.
so this is the lambda expression equivalent to the following

```
   static <T> Function<T, T> identity() {
        return new Function<>() {
            @Override
            public Object apply(Object t) {
                return t;
            }
        };
    }
```